# Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) Error in python

Tags: python

i'm trying to make a program that displays a web browser in a program
this is my code:

```
import tkinter
import webview

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("696x696")
window.title("sea camer")
window.config(background="#00ffff") 
webview.create_window('sea camer', 'http://178.183.165.53:25100/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=0&subtype=0')
webview.start()
```

this is the error message i got:

````
 Unable to load DLL 'WebView2Loader.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(String browserExecutableFolder, String userDataFolder, ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options, ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler environment_created_handler)
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2Environment.<CreateAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2.<InitCoreWebView2Async>d__25.MoveNext()```

 I was expecting it to open a gui that shows the webpage but instead it opened the gui but the web page part resulted in an error.
````

Answer (score 1):

The `webview` module calls a C# DLL that in turn uses the WebView2 package, which is part of Microsoft Edge.  That package is not built-in, and needs to be installed.  According to the docs, that package can only be installed using the Visual Studio IDE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/how-to/machine-setup#install-the-webview2-sdk

It's a lot of trouble.  You might consider instead using the `webbrowser` module, which is part of the Python standard library.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html